# Auto joining relations in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

Hello I've created a base REST Controller for my Rails application and I am struggling to get my ActiveRecord models to join for requests.

My goal is to accomplish something like this:

Request: GET /appointment
Response:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "customer_id":3,
        "customer":{
            "name":"John Doe"
        },
        "date":"2011-11-11T00:00:00.000Z",
        "created_at":null,
        "updated_at":null,
        "employee_id":1,
        "employee":{
            "name":"Jane Doe"
        }
    }
]
```

However I am just getting this:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "customer_id":3,
        "date":"2011-11-11T00:00:00.000Z",
        "created_at":null,
        "updated_at":null,
        "employee_id":1
    }
]
```

Here's my base REST Controller: http://pastebin.com/gQqBNeCH
You can read the entire thing if you want, otherwise you can just read the code I'm focusing on:

```
def index
  @objects = get_class().all

  @objects.each do |x|
    x.get_relations
  end

  render json: @objects
end
```

Here's my Appointment model

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :employee

  attr_accessor :customer

  validates :customer_id, presence: true, :numericality => {
    :only_integer => true,
    :allow_blank => false,
    :greater_than => 0
    }

  validates :employee_id, :numericality => {
    :only_integer => true,
    :allow_blank => false,
    :greater_than => 0
    }

  validates :date, presence: true

  def get_relations
    @customer = Customer.find(self.customer_id)
  end

end
```

My original method was just to use a member variable like such:

```
def get_relations
  @customer = Customer.find(self.customer_id)
end
```

However it looks like ActiveRecord has some sort of serializer method it runs with render. Any advice of how to attach my belongs_to relations to that object?

Comment: +1... for well written and formatted question. Nice Man!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the way AR renders objects to json, you can override the `as_json` method (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json) in your model. But that would mean putting presentation information within your model which I'm not a big fan of.

You can also include the relation in your `to_json` call:

```
render :json => @objects.to_json(:include => :relation)
```

But in your case, as you're building an api I would look into some more advanced JSON formatting options such [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) or [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)

Comment: +1 for JBuilder...  There's a lot of value in being explicit!

Comment: You could also simply have json.erb or json.ruby views if you wanted. If you don't want to get too many gems in your app it is another valid option.

Comment: RABL will be the best option to use. Where you can create a nodes with relations.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include it in your json response explicitly

```
def index
  @objects = get_class().all
  render json: @objects.to_json(:include => [:employee, :company])
end
```